# Coded UI test screen rotation on windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, coded-ui-tests, screen-rotation

I have to test screen rotation of windows phone by Coded UI in Visual Studio 2013 update 3.
Does Coded UI test screen rotation on windows phone? What does it use?
Please help me.
Thank you for help